# How to modify the name of an ad-hoc Stereotype in Sparx EA

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, stereotype

I have a number of "ad-hoc" stereotypes in a Sparx EA model.  That is, I just typed a stereotype name in the element properties, then used the same name in other elements to which it applies ... without using a profiles.

Each of these then appears in `Project --> Settings --> UML Types --> Stereotypes`.

Eventually, I added Shape Script icons, etc.

However, I created some confusion with one Stereotype name. I used "Tablespace" as a design concept to indicate "group of related database tables".   Our database team finds this confusing due to the physical concept of a "tablespace" in Oracle.

So, I want to rename.

If I do this from `UML Types --> Stereotypes`, all of the existing elements retain the original name (eg. Tablespace) and revert to their Shape Script-less appearance.  If I visit an element and change to the new name, the Shape Script, etc. appears.

I'm not keen on finding each element with stereotype and manually applying the new name.

Is it time for me to learn EA Scripting or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only escape is using the automation (or native DB access). If your stereotype is just used in objects you may iterate over the result of

`Repository.SQLQuery("SELECT object_id FROM t_object WHERE stereotype='oldStereo'")`

to get all object ids. Then you need to

`elem = Repository.GetElementByID(theId)`

to retrieve the single elements. Finally you can change the stereotype with

```
elem.stereotype = "newStereo"
elem.update()
```

You can also run a direct SQL with

```
Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_object SET stereotype='new' WHERE stereotype='old'")
```

Note that the latter uses one of the landmine functions not being supported officially.

**Edit**: You might also run the last SQL in a native RDBMS client. When using EAP you might need to rename it temporarily to `.mdb` to pretend it's an MS Access database (which it actually is).

Comment: Did as you suggested and posted my (JScript, uses EA Lib DB scripts) code in separate answer. Accepting your answer since it led me to solution.   HOWEVER ... when I re-query with new Stereotype name, I find Objects. BUT, when I print their `.stereotype`, the old name appears.  Similar if I double click on one in an exsiting diagram.  The diagram shows the old name, double clicking and the text shows new Stereotype name in properties, but clicking the "..." beside has old Stereotype name selected, and not new.  It's like the update wasn't "deep" enough.  Ideas?

Comment: Held off accepting until completely resolved ... got to the bottom of it with a RTFM, leading to the stereotypeEx attribute, which seemed to be the missing link.

Comment: Accepted the answer since the real question was "do I need to script to to this" and you answered that.  The provision of the "how" is a bonus.  I just wasn't sure how to handle this since the best "how" answer in in mine with stereotypeEx ... and so have to hope anyone coming here with same problem will read all comments and pick up on that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this VBScript to rename stereotypes in EA.

It has been tested on a .eap file, and it is this complicated because of the lack of `replace()` in MS Access SQL syntax.

Just go the the Scripting view, add a new VBScript and paste this code to your new script. Then modify it to indicate the from and to stereotypes.

```vbs
option explicit

!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-VBScript

'
' Script Name: Rename Stereotypes
' Author: Geert Bellekens
' Purpose: Rename stereotypes on all types of elements 
' Environment: Tested on .eap file.
' Date: 13/10/2015
'
sub main
    renameElementStereotypes "FromStereo", "ToStereo"
    renameAttributeStereotypes "FromStereo", "ToStereo"
    renameConnectorStereotypes "FromStereo", "ToStereo"
    renameOperationStereotypes "FromStereo", "ToStereo"
    renameDiagramStereotypes "FromStereo", "ToStereo"
    Repository.RefreshModelView(0)
    msgbox "Finished renaming stereotypes"
end sub

sub renameElementStereotypes(fromStereo, toStereo)
    renameStereotypes "t_object", fromStereo, toStereo
end sub
sub renameAttributeStereotypes(fromStereo, toStereo)
    renameStereotypes "t_attribute", fromStereo, toStereo
end sub
sub renameConnectorStereotypes(fromStereo, toStereo)
    renameStereotypes "t_connector", fromStereo, toStereo
end sub
sub renameOperationStereotypes(fromStereo, toStereo)
    renameStereotypes "t_operation", fromStereo, toStereo
end sub
sub renameDiagramStereotypes(fromStereo, toStereo)
    renameStereotypes "t_diagram", fromStereo, toStereo
end sub

sub renameStereotypes (baseTable, fromStereo, toStereo)
    dim updateSQL
    'first the second part of of t_xref description
    updateSQL = "update (" & baseTable & " o inner join t_xref x on o.[ea_guid] = x.[Client]) "&_
               " set x.Description = MID( x.Description, 1, INSTR(  x.Description, ':" & fromStereo & "') - 1) "&_
                         " + ':" & toStereo & "' "&_
                         " + MID(x.Description,INSTR(  x.Description, ':" & fromStereo & "') "&_ 
                              " + LEN(':" & fromStereo & "'), LEN(x.Description)  "&_
                              " - INSTR(  x.Description, ':" & fromStereo & "') "&_
                              " - LEN(':" & fromStereo & "')+ 1) "&_
               " where o.Stereotype = '" & fromStereo & "' "&_
               "  and x.Name = 'Stereotypes' "&_
               " and INSTR(  x.Description, ':" & fromStereo & "') > 0  "              
    Repository.Execute updateSQL
    'then the first part of t_xref description
    updateSQL = "update (" & baseTable & " o inner join t_xref x on o.[ea_guid] = x.[Client]) "&_
               " set x.Description = MID( x.Description, 1, INSTR(  x.Description, '=" & fromStereo & "') - 1) "&_
                         " + '=" & toStereo & "' "&_
                         " + MID(x.Description,INSTR(  x.Description, '=" & fromStereo & "') "&_ 
                              " + LEN('=" & fromStereo & "'), LEN(x.Description)  "&_
                              " - INSTR(  x.Description, '=" & fromStereo & "') "&_
                              " - LEN('=" & fromStereo & "')+ 1) "&_
               " where o.Stereotype = '" & fromStereo & "' "&_
               "  and x.Name = 'Stereotypes' "&_               
               " and INSTR(  x.Description, '=" & fromStereo & "') > 0  "
    Repository.Execute updateSQL                
    'then the stereotype itself
    updateSQL = " update " & baseTable & " o "&_
                " set o.[Stereotype] = '" & toStereo & "' "&_
                " where o.Stereotype = '" & fromStereo & "' "
    Repository.Execute updateSQL
end sub

main
```

Comment: I like that this answer is more comprehensive and includes all types.  As someone new to EA Scripting, I found the challenge of working from the model directly good for learning, which is why I accepted @Thomas Killian's answer.   At same time, note problems in my comment to his answer.  Does this direct SQL avoid those issues?

Comment: It probably will, but you should reload the model to be sure you still have issues with the stereotype after running your script.

Comment: I've updated my answer re/ StereotypeEx.  Not sure if that would need to be reflected in the direct SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the script I created, based on @Thomas Killian's answer.

Improvements:

1. Uses the EAScriptLib Database functions to get the result.
2. Proper case on Update() method (didn't seem essential, though)
3. Also sets the StereotypeEx attribute on the Object/Element. *This seems to be critical... otherwise, the change is either ignored or new stereotype is simply added to the list of stereotypes for the object*

Also, unsure how much it matters, but did not open the components via Project Browser before running script during final testing.  This feels like voodoo.

```
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-JScript
!INC EAScriptLib.JScript-Database

function RenameStereotypes()
{
    Repository.EnsureOutputVisible( "Script" );

    var objectIDs = DBGetFieldValueArrayString( "object_id" /* : String */, "t_object" /* : String */,  "stereotype='DBTables'" /* : String */ ); /* : Array */

    Session.Output( objectIDs );

    for ( var i = 0; i < objectIDs.length; i++ ) {
        var theId = objectIDs[i];
        var elem = Repository.GetElementByID(theId);
        Session.Output( "Id: " + theId + " Name: " + elem.name + " Stereotype: " + elem.stereotype );
        elem.stereotype = "DBTables";    /* FIRST VISIBLE STEREOTYPE */
        elem.stereotypeEx = "DBTables";  /* CRITICAL - DEEPER LIST OF STEREOTYPES */
        elem.Update();  /* CASE CHANGED, NOT SURE IT MATTERS */
        elem.Refresh(); /* JUST IN CASE */
    }
}

RenameStereotypes();
```